# Trying to fix [object Object] for my Word Dictionary bot

Tags: javascript, object, bots, discord.js

So I downloaded this node js module called word-definition, you can check word-definition [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/word-definition).

It worked well in the `console.log` part, but not the `message.channel.send` part.

In the `console log` the definition was there, but my bot messages "[object Object]".

```js
let word = arg.slice(0).join(" ");

if (!word) {
 message.reply("\nThat's not how you use a Dictionary nyan~!");
} else {
 const wd = require("word-definition");

 wd.getDef(`${word}`, "en", null, function(definition) {
  message.channel.send(`${definition}`)//This says [object Object]
  console.log(definition);//This works
  /*Console.log example where the word is "dog"
  {
  word: 'dog',
  category: 'noun',
  definition: 'A mammal, Canis lupus familiaris, that has been domesticated for ' 
  +
  'thousands of years, of highly variable appearance due to human ' +
  'breeding.'
  }
  */
});
```

Note: I am using discord.js v12 btw

Comment: Please show the result of "console.log(definition);" or example in same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wd.getDef` returns an object with the properties `word`, `category`, and `definition`
change

`message.channel.send(defintion)` into `message.channel.send(definition.definition)`

Might wanna rename the variable to `props` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use JSON.stringify() like this:   `message.channel.send(JSON.stringify(definition))`